# HTML5 app routing, pushState

Tags: jquery, html, routes, pushstate

I'm trying to do two things:

Use pushState to change the URL

```
//Video
$("a").click(function(){
history.pushState(null, "Video", "/video/");
return false;
});
```

and then be able to route that link to show a div if anyone types it into their browser:

```
www.mysite.com/video/ ---> show div
```

I've been looking at a few scripts: davis.js, sammy.js, history.js

Do I need any of these scripts? Is there a way in jQuery to do this?

Answer (score 5):

I'm slightly biased since I'm the author of Davis.js, but I think using a routing lib like Davis.js or Sammy.js is the simplest way to get this done.  Both libraries have code to manage what happens when a link is clicked or the back and forward button are used to navigate between states and all the other peculiarities of the history API.

If you want something really simple then you could code something up yourself, although this may take a little longer than just using a lib.

Here is a rough idea of what you could do:

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var link = $(this)
  history.pushState({pushedByMe: true}, link.attr('title'), link.attr('href'))
  yourCodeHere()
})

history.onpopstate = function (event) {
 if (!event.state.pushedByMe) return
 yourCodeHere()
}
```